# Testing to make sure response.body contains the right tags in the head of the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom, testing

Im writing a test to check that there are OpenGraph meta tags present on a certain page. The test has been written as below.

```
test "og tags are present" do
  get :bid, id: auctions(:name)
  assert_response :success
  assert_select "head" do
    assert_select "meta" do
      assert_match /og:title/, response.body
      assert_match /og:type/, response.body
      assert_match /og:url/, response.body
      assert_match /og:image/, response.body
      assert_match /og:description/, response.body
    end
  end
end
```

I think there is an easier way to do this possibly without looking at the whole `response.body` in the `assert_match` calls. I just want to look at what is within the meta tags nested in the head tags. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe less readeble, but also less verbose. You could try with something like:

```
test "og tags are present" do
  get :bid, id: auctions(:name)
  assert_response :success
  assert_select "head" do
    assert_select "meta" do
      ['title', 'type', 'url', 'image', 'description'].each do |mt|
         assert_match Regexp.new('og:' + mt), response.body
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If there is a way to retrieve all the nested meta tags in the `head` you could do:

```
# metatags => array with head meta tags
metatags.each do |mt|
  assert_match Regexp.new('og:' + mt), response.body
end
```

**UPDATE**
Are you using [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)? Because with this tool you can retrieve the meta tags with this simple command:

```
page.find(:xpath, '//html/head/meta', visible: false)
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks, nice solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions is not the best way to test html output unless its a really simple string because it is very error prone. Take this example:

```
assert_match /og:title/, '<meeta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />'
```

Which will give a false postive since Regexps don't grokk HTML.

Instead you would use a HTML parser like Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
# Query the document and build a hash out of the open graph tags
meta = doc.css('meta[property^="og:"]').inject({}) do |result, node|
  result[node.attr('property')] = node.attr('content')
  result
end

# example data from http://ogp.me/
assert_equals "The Rock", meta["og:title"]
assert_equals "video.movie", meta["og:type"]
assert_equals "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/", meta["og:url"]
assert_equals "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg", meta["og:image"]
```

Here we just turn the open graph tags into a hash so that we can write simple assertions about their content.

If you don't care about the content property you could do it without Nokogiri like so:

```
assert_false( css_select('meta[property="og:title"]').empty? )
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with `Capybara::Node::Simple` which is just sugar on top of nokogiri.